# Matrix Synapse search on Arch Linux

Tags: search, arch-linux

I just installed a Matrix Synapse homeserver from the community repo on Arch Linux, and searching for text in room messages doesn't work.

I tried searching for text in both the desktop Riot.im client and the mobile app, and neither one returns text which I know exists because I just copied and pasted it from a message visible on the screen.

I then realized I have end-to-end encryption turned on in that room and presumably search is done on the server. So I created a new room with no encryption and tried again; still no luck.

I looked in the config file for "search" and "index" to see if there's some indexing switch I need to flip, but the only option I see is `search_all_users`. That pertains to searching for users, not searching for text within messages in rooms.

Help, please? How do I get message-search working, and am I correct in assuming it won't work with end-to-end encryption?

Thanks.

PS: I tried adding matrix, synapse, and riot.im tags but they don't yet exist and I don't have enough reputation to create them.

EDIT: I reinstalled the synapse server and it worked this time. I forgot to save the config but I ran the same config-editing script this time that I did before, so unless I additionally changed something else by accident the first time I'm running the same config. Not sure what went wrong before, so I'm not going to post this as an answer.